# Getting paragraph styles in apache POI, language specific

Tags: java, windows, ms-word, apache-poi

Is it possible to get the styles of a paragraph in a particular langage ?. For example: on my personal computer I happen to have a dutch installation of microsoft windows. this is resulting in the paragraph.getStyles() method returning the dutch values of the styles, instead of a normal value of "heading1", "heading2" etc I am receiving values such as"Kop1", "kop2".

I am creating a parser for word based documents which selects certain parts on style. does anyone have any experience with this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at the data in the .docx file (it's a zip-file) to verify if the data is written this way by Word already or "transposed" by POI or some local functionality.

If the data is already written by Word you will need to check how you can create the document in a different language in Word.

If not, then if you are using POI 3.13 or newer, you can try to set a different locale via `LocaleUtil.setUserLocale()` and see if that affects the results.

Comment: Setting the locale might be the solution. I will have a look at this as soon as i am able to. Let me get back at this.